# Accepting '#' in query string in Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have an end point that accept username as query string but this username might have # in the beginning so in Joi I got this

```
{
    "code": 1021,
    "message": "Request data model validation has failed",
    "id": "276ba99a-2abc-4505-b66a-dad2a8ger5",
    "explanation": [
        "`username` is not allowed to be empty"
    ]
}
```

how can I make my query string accept # in the beginning using Joi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode your param before adding it to the URL.

```
const url = 'https://example.com?username=#allia';
const response = await fetch(encodeURIComponent(url));
```

Or you can replace `#` by `%23`

Comment: You might want to give him the general solution of encoding with `encodeURIComponent` or something.

Comment: @Martial Thank you I know but I wonder if I can do it through Joi or if there is any other way so I will not enforce the consumer of my api to  encode the param before sending it

Comment: @MatJ I don't know anything about Joi. That's why I didn't mention `encodeURIComponent` beacause maybe Joi has its own encoding process.

Comment: @allia Since `#` is interpreted in URL, if the user wants to send data with this symbol, they gonna have to encode it anyway.

Comment: @Martial, no problem. `joi` is about object validation, input sanitation has to be done separately from validation anyway.